# Как передавать местоположение пользователя, чтобы на html-странице можно было наблюдать, как он движется

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, геолокация, webapi

Как лучше всего передать местоположение пользователя, чтобы на html-странице можно было наблюдать за тем, как движется другой пользователь. Что-то вроде пассажира отслеживающего движения такси к вам. Я использую .Net Core для бэкэнда и (CSS, HTML, jQuery, TypeScript) для фронта. Есть ли для этого API Google, или нужно использовать что-то вроде веб-сокетов или SignalR для отправки координат через определенный промежуток времени?

Я предполагаю, что-то вроде этого: нужно отправлять координаты движущегося пользователя на сервер через определенные промежутки времени (при этом записывать их в базу или нет я еще не знаю) и отправлять их наблюдающему пользователю с сервера, используя для отображения карты Google. Нужно ли записывать координаты в базе данных или есть другой способ передать их наблюдающему пользователю для отображения.

Может кто-то сталкивался с этим, скажите пожалуйста, какие технологии или API лучше использовать. Спасибо.

Comment: Записывать в базу нужно, если вы хотите показать или сохранить маршрут.

Comment: @aepot. То-есть, мне нужно записывать координаты в базу а потом сразу же брать из базы последние координаты и показывать расположение с помощью google api, так?

Comment: Я использовал Яндекс.Карты для отрисовки карты, а маршрут на карте просто рисовал по своим данным из базы, без передачи данных в Яндекс. Данные от мобильного приложения поступали на сервер обычными HTTPS Post запросами, раз в 10 секунд. Никаких сокетов для получения геолокации не использовалось. Для отображения в браузере, использовался WebSocket, чтобы не долбить сервер частыми запросами на обновление данных, сервер просто так же раз в те же 10 секунд слал в браузер новые данные, что получил. Обратите внимание, у Яндекса надо покупать лицензию при использовании карт в целях диспетчеризации.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за совет

Comment: Так, только уточню: GPS вам пришлет точные координаты, вам просто надо эти координаты наложить на карту. При этом совершенно не важно, что именно за карта используется. Координаты не надо отправлять в гугл или откуда там ваша карта, их просто прямо в браузере нужно отдать загруженной карте в JS "карта, поставь мне пожалуйста точку на этих координатах"

Comment: @aepot спасибо за помощь)